# I was setting up Android device manager service

Tags: google-play-store

It show me to ring ur phone when I select allowed it automatically locked my device and now it is not getting my password it is showing wrong password how can I turn it off .. Even I signed in into that account by my another device please help me out

Answer (score 0):

I wood log in to you Google account and reset ur password and then shut the locked phone off and leave it off for a good 5 minutes and I'd pull the battery if possible but that's your call and then turn it back on and try the new password if not try the support page for adm which u should have done by now  i was taught if all else fales go to the source​

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3265955?visit_id=1-636282398145671585-3604311919&p=device_manager_location&rd=1